# Resistor annotated with a frequency

Tags: resistors, switch-mode-power-supply, dc-dc-converter, frequency, schematics

The [LT3757 datasheet](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/3757Afe.pdf) includes the following schematic:

[image: Schematic]

The resistor in the bottom left corner is annotated with a frequency (100kHz).  What is the significance of that annotation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That resistor sets the frequency of the DC to DC converter, the frequency will be set at 100KHz. Shown below is a table from the datasheet of other values for the Rt resistor that can change the switching frequency.

[image]
[image]
Source: https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/3757Afe.pdf

Answer (score 3):

If you'll notice in the features section of the linked datasheet:

[image: The features section of the linked datasheet. "Programmable Operating Frequency (100kHz to 1MHz) with One External Resistor" is highlighted.]

It states that one resistor can be used to set its operating frequency. Evidently, a 140k resistor sets it to its minimum of 100kHz.

On page 11 of the datasheet, Table 1 (shown below) provides resistances to be used for several example frequencies.

[image: A table of frequencies vs resistances, showing 100 kHz corresponds to 140 kΩ.]

Comment: You need to provide a source if taking screenshots and provide a link

Comment: @VoltageSpike I specifically mentioned that these came from the datasheet linked in the question.